# How to use a thread created inside one class in a different class?

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to use a thread created inside one class in a different class.
This is the code which creates a thread :

```
        Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d ("Thread", "Thread has started");
                processImage(data, size.width, size.height, camera);
                camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
                Log.d ("Thread", "Thread has ended");
            }
        });

        if (!background.isAlive())
        {
            background.setPriority (10);
            background.start();
        }
```

Now, when I'm in the camera mode and I wish to go back, I want the main thread to wait till the thread has finished doing it's work. So I figured, if I add `background.join()` in the `surfaceDestroyed()` function of the `SurfaceView` class, I should be able to get the desired outcome. But the problem is, the thread is not created in the `SurfaceView` class. So what do I do? How do I use that particular thread in the `SurfaceView` class?

Comment: Can you not simply pass it in as a Thread parameter to surfaceDestroyed()?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can store `background` in a static variable and access it that way?